# How to check String in Array List from SQLite

Tags: android, string, sqlite, arraylist

in my android app i have an SQLite Database with phone number (here I changed the numbers with other inexistent for privacy)!

```
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
```

I created a List containing the numbers from database and printed on the screen to see if it works and it give me back correct the numbers!

```
List numeri = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllNumeri();
System.out.println("num tel: " + phone);

It give me back two numbers present in database --> [3401234567, 02123456]
```

Then i tryed to compare the incoming number of a call with this List with this metod:

```
String phone = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
System.out.println("Incoming number - " + phone);

    boolean retval = numeri.contains(phone); 

    if (retval == true) {
      System.out.println("PHONE is contained in the list");
     }
    else {
      System.out.println("PHONE is not contained in the list");
     }
```

I tryed to call with my number 3401234567!

```
The println give me back: Incoming number: +393401234567
```

and

```
The condition give me back that "PHONE is not contained in the list!"
```

I tryed also to change database numbers by adding the national prefix (+39) but it don t works!

Can anyone help me? Thanks

I think it isn t duplicate because in other question, compare two string, here i want compare one string with arraylist

Comment: U're doing it right, you may try to debug the code that's what i recommend

Comment: You should select the number from ur database instead of selecting all and then do list search. For example when u get the number do a selection statement that retuens that number if found else it doesn't

Comment: @k0sh you can give me an help with this example???

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the return type of

```
mySQLiteAdapter.getAllNumeri()
```

if its number, then the below statement might not give the desired output as you are trying to compare the numbers with the Strings.

```
boolean retval = numeri.contains(phone);
```

Comment: getAllNumeri() give me back List with Strings....